# Using x509 Cert with Savon v2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wcf, x509certificate, savon

I am getting the following response from XML Request to WCF Service with Savon from Ruby on Rails.

```
<s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The security context token is expired or is not valid. The message was not processed.</s:Text>
```

The Web Service I am hitting uses x509 certificate.  They sent me 3 .cer files which are named:

- ABCInternalIssuingCA.cer
- ABCInternalRootCA.cer
- ABCInternalIntermediateCA.cer

I am on a Windows 2008 Server so using mmc I moved these certificates to certificate store under Local Computer.  I also have the pfx file from the Web Service and the password.  Having read through the Savon documentation I have configured my client as below:

```
  client = Savon.client(wsdl: WSDL_URL,
                        log: true, # set to true to switch on logging
                        log_level: :debug,
                        convert_request_keys_to: :none,
                        pretty_print_xml: true,
                        ssl_cert_file: "lib/ABCInternalIssuingCA.cer",
                        ssl_ca_cert_file: "lib/ABCInternalRootCA.cer",
                        ssl_cert_key_file: "lib/MyKeyFile.pfx",
                        ssl_cert_key_password: "password",
                        soap_version: 2
                      )
```

Note I copied the *.cer files and the pfx file into my lib folder in Ruby solution.  Is there something incorrect with my setting up off the x509 that is throwing the error message above and has anyone had any luck in using Savon with x509's?

UPDATE:

Used SSL and created .pem files for each just to copy what is on the Savon Documentation  [site](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html) but still getting the same error message above

Comment: Any news in half a year?

Comment: No I convinced my superiors to change the whole project to asp.net mvc 5

Comment: By switching to "asp.net mvc 5" you may probably upgraded .NET framework from 4.0 to 4.5 as a side effect?